# what does this expression mean ? var x = (function () {})();

Tags: javascript

```
var x = (function () {

some code

})();
```

What this kind of expression called, what does it mean?
This part defined a object and include some function inside. I am confused about why there need to be a () in the end.

Comment: x is the return value of the function. the () in the end is just to execute the function.

Comment: It's called an IIFE, and the result it returns is assigned to the variable `x`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {

some code

})();
```

Above code is self invoking function (IIFE).  var x= IIFE will assign the value reutrned by IIFE to x.

Here is great post explaining IIFE
http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/